# Red5phone Busy or Rejected before call established?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, phone-call, red5

I did like this :
1. install red5,asterisk
2. setting environment variable, such as java, apache-ant
3. configure sip.conf at asterisk
4. Running Red5phone

It's successfully registered, but when I call between two client the Red5phone ended calling and shows that Busy or Rejected?

I don't have any idea about it. What must I do?

thanks in advance.

My sip.conf configuration :

```
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr =0.0.0.0
context=lain-lain
allowoverlap=no
srvlookup=yes

[1000]
username=1000
secret=1234
host=dynamic
disallow=all
qualify=yes
type=peer
context=digium
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw

[1001]
username=1001
secret=1234
host=dynamic
disallow=all
qualify=yes
type=peer
context=digium
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
```

my extensions.conf :

```
[globals]
[general]
autofallthrough=yes
[lain-lain]
[digium]
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/1000)
exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/1001)
include => internal
include => remote

[internal]
# This is how we get to our voicemail. Dial 123 from any SIP connected phone.
exten => 123,1,Answer()
exten => 123,2,VoiceMailMain(0203123456)
exten => 123,3,Hangup()
# If we’re trying to call any extension that starts with the number 2 and has 4 digits only, assume internal.
exten => _2XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _2XXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},30)
exten => _2XXX,n,Playback(the-party-you-are-calling&is-curntly-unavail)
exten => _2XXX,n,Hangup()

[remote]
# Anything that isn’t internal we send to the PSTN.
exten => _X!,1,NoOp()
exten => _X!,n,Dial(SIP/siptrunk/${EXTEN})
exten => _X!,n,Hangup()

[incoming]
# This is where calls coming in from the PSTN are directed – see context setting in sip.conf
exten => _X.,1,NoOp()
# Try and call the desktop and mobile. If this fails, direct to voicemail.
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/jamesdesktop)
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/jamesmobile)
exten => _X.,n,VoiceMail(0203123456,u)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Have you tried logging into the Asterisk console and executing 'SIP SET DEBUG' and watching the conversation?  Are both extensions properly registering?  I also don't see the outbound leg of your SIP provider in your sip.conf.

Comment: it shows warning at asterisk "No application dial for extension(telpun,2002,1)"

Comment: Are you dialing extension 2002?  Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: sorry, i make mistake. I means "No application dial for extension(telpun,1001,1)"

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks to @gnxtech3 for your attention

finally, I make it. the solution is about configuration at module.conf

i put this line of code at my module.conf :

> [modules]
>
> .
>   .
>
> load = app_dial.so

dont forget to reload asterisk.